# rxJs filter list with debounce based on emitted value in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, filtering, observable

I have an input control for backend filtering of a list.
I have set up an observable for the keyup event of the input control.

What i cannot figure out how to do is to immediately process the request if the user pressed enter key.

So debounce's timer should be dependent on the emitted value of the debounced observable. I assume Debounce does not reevaluate its parameter on stream emission, but i tried it using an external variable without success - which seems like a hack anyway.
Also if there is a less hacky way to handle escape (without external variables) please point me to the proper direction!

Another issue is that holding a key to repeatedly enter characters make this code lag since i'm on keyup event to get the control keys (esc for ex).
Can this be throttled without loosing keypresses?

Or should i hook to some angular event if a suitable one exists instead of keyup?

```
                    let lastValue: string = '';
                    let debounceTime: number = 550;

                    Observable.fromEvent(ctrl.nativeElement, 'keyup')
                    .takeUntil(this.destroyedSignal)
                    .map((key:any)=>{
                        if (key.keyCode == 27 || key.keyCode == 13){
                            this.getColumnDef(fieldName).showFilterInput = false;
                            debounceTime = 0;
                            if (key.keyCode === 27) {
                                ctrl.nativeElement.value = lastValue;
                            }
                        } else {
                          debounceTime = 550;
                        }
                        return key;
                    })
                    .debounceTime(debounceTime)
                    .filter((key:any)=>this.isValidFilterKey(key.keyCode)) // no api call for control chars
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .subscribe((key) => { 
                      //send filtervalue to a behaviorsubject that triggers api call .. 
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what all your code is supposed to do, but I can help you out with listening to *Enter*.

```
let lastValue: string = '';
let debounceTime: number = 550;

const keyUp$ = Observable.fromEvent(ctrl.nativeElement, 'keyup').share(); // 1

keyUp$
    .takeUntil(this.destroyedSignal)
    .do(_ =>{ // 2
        if (key.keyCode == 27 || key.keyCode == 13){
            this.getColumnDef(fieldName).showFilterInput = false;
            debounceTime = 0;
            if (key.keyCode === 27) {
                ctrl.nativeElement.value = lastValue;
            }
        } else {
            debounceTime = 550;
        }
    })
    .debounceTime(debounceTime)
    .filter((key:any)=>this.isValidFilterKey(key.keyCode)) // no api call for control chars
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .merge(keyUp$.filter((key: any) => key.keyCode == 13)) // 3
    .subscribe((key) => { 
        //send filtervalue to a behaviorsubject that triggers api call .. 
    }
```

1. We need to subscribe to the same observable multiple times. When doing this, we share the observable between all the subscribers. We store this shared observable in a seperate variable.
2. I changed the `map` to a `do`. You'll get the same result, but you're more clearly stating your intent. `map` is for changing a value, `do` is for *side effects*, eg. "stuff outside of the observable"
3. Here we merge the "old" observable with a new one that will only singal on keyUp for *Enter*. As it is after the `debounceTime`, it won't be debounced and signal the `subscribe` immediately

I hope this helps. You're mixing Rx with some regular imperative code, so it's a bit difficult to see the overall intention.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much cleaner.
The regular code's purpose is to reset the input to the last accepted value on escape.
Couldn't figure a way so far to get rid of that and do it via rx purely.